# Spring security, test MVC and mock services

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-security, mockmvc

I want to test my controller, which has `@PreAuthorize` and also it has service which i want to mock

PlayerController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/player")
public class PlayerController {
  @Autowired
  private PlayerService playerService;

  @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
  @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
  public
  @ResponseBody
  ResponseEntity<List<String>> loadByAdmin()
  throws Exception {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(playerService.getPlayers(), HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

PlayerServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class PlayerServiceImpl implements PlayerService{
  @Autowired
  private PlayerRepo playerRepo;

  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public List<String> getPlayers()() {
    return playerRepo.findAll();
  }
}
```

First try: In this case - test works, but as you can see `authority` is `SOMEONE` so it should be fail because only authority `ADMIN` is accessed.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebAppConfig.class, SecurityConfiguration.class})
public class PlayerControllerTest {
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Autowired
  private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

  @Mock
  private PlayerService playerService;

  @InjectMocks
  private PlayerController playerController;

  @Test
  public void loadByAdmin()
  throws Exception {
    Player player = new player();
    when(playerService.getPlayers()).thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(player));

    mockMvc.perform(get("/circuit/all").with(user("adm").password("123")
        .authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("SOMEONE"))) //not failed
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());

    verify(playerService, times(1)).getPlayers();
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(playerService);
  }


  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
        .standaloneSetup(playerController)
        .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity(springSecurityFilterChain))
        .build();
}
```

Second try: So i try another method, it works right for different authorities, but in this case i can't to mock PlayerService

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebAppConfig.class, SecurityConfiguration.class})
public class PlayerControllerTest {
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext wac;

  @Mock
  private PlayerService playerService;

  @InjectMocks
  private PlayerController playerController;

  @Test
  public void loadByAdmin()
  throws Exception {
    Player player = new player();
    when(playerService.getPlayers()).thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(player)); //not mocked

    mockMvc.perform(get("/circuit/all").with(user("adm").password("123")
        .authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN")))
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());

    verify(playerService, times(1)).getPlayers(); //no interaction
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(playerService);  //no interaction
  }


  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    this.mockMvc.webAppContextSetup(wac)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
}
```

So, what can i do for mock `PlayerService` and test Authorization?

Comment: try calling MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); after this.mockMvc.....build()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved with reflection

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebAppConfig.class})
public class PlayerControllerTest {
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Mock
  private PlayerService playerService;

  @Autowired
  private PlayerController playerController;

  @Autowired
  private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

  @Test
  public void loadByAdmin()
  throws Exception {
    Player player = new player();
    when(playerService.getPlayers()).thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(player)); //success

    mockMvc.perform(get("/circuit/all").with(user("adm").password("123")
        .authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN")))
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());

    verify(playerService, times(1)).getPlayers(); //was called
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(playerService);  
  }


  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(playerController)
        .apply(springSecurity(springSecurityFilterChain)).build();

    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(playerController, "playerService", playerService);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the PlayerService impl?

Also you may try to `@Autowire on playerService` and add a palyer on setUp method, do the check on players with admin authority, in @After remove that player. Since this is an integration test @Autowire should work.

Comment: add PlayerServiceImpl, but @Autowired couldn't use because PlayerServiceImpl works with database and when it call getPlayers it get real data from db

Comment: you can then either try to run it with @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) or instanciate the playerService class as playerService = Mockito.mock(PlayerService.class);

Comment: `@Mock private PlayerService playerService` with `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` it is eq to `playerService = Mockito.mock(PlayerService.class); `